# Set Line-Ending of editor according to existing file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, editor

I normally work on Windows and CRLF is probably used.
However, when I work in a project that already uses LF for all files, the setting you see in the status bar still remains CRLF. I have to change this for each file individually, otherwise the linter (Prettier - Code formatter in my case) complains.

How can I achieve this better?

I would prefer it if vscode did it like Visual Studio: Decide how it is used in the existing file.

Note: The setting "files.eol": "\n" only ensures that LF is used for new files instead of CRLF.